# ASP.NET - How to draw a signature on pdf?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm building a system using `Asp.Net MVC` and I have some .pdf contracts into the project where my users need to print, sign and send it to me, then, I was thinking about to create a way where user can to draw his signature with mouse as a pencil  and after that save file into a folder.

How could I do this, is there a library to do ?

Comment: I think this link will help you [link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/302519?decorator=print&displayFullThread=true)

Comment: @MohammadDaliri thanks for your attention. I saw your link suggestion but it does not clearly how to do what I need. It only has random questions and answers and it is confuse to me because there's no begin as a "what I need to start ?". Can you understand me ?

Comment: @FernandoPaiva did you ever find a solution? This is quite a common requirement nowadays for people signing for deliveries on a mobile device